# mbstring apache php server 2008

Tags: apache, php, mbstring

I have just completed a clean install of server 2008 with apache and php.

all was workign great but having issues with phpmyadmin. digging furhter it seemed that the mbstring library was not being loaded.

looking ay phpinfo() it outputs the following:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\php\php.ini

I have cheacked to make sure that no php.ini file exists in wondows.

the c:\php\php.ini file looks as follows:

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

when looking through phpinfo() I cannot see that the mbstring library has loaded even after an apache restart?

any advice? thanks,

Comment: did you check if you've actually got that .dll file?

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your time.C:\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll does exist.